# iterate over pandas data frame from a specific row index

Tags: python, pandas

I can iterate over a pandas dataframe using the `iterrows` function but I wonder how one can iterate over the rows from a given index?

I know one can do something like:

```
index_to_start = 100
current = 0
for _, row in frame.iterrows():
    if current < index_to_start:
        continue
    # Do something
```

However, this seems a bit ugly and I wonder if there is a clearer and more straight forward way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need additional `if` to control

```
index_to_start = 100
for _, row in frame.iloc[index_to_start:,:].iterrows():
    #do something
```

Also , in pandas we usually do not iterrows.

You can do `np.where`

```
np.where(df.reset_index().index<100, 'nothing', ' do someting')
```

Comment: My frame index is actually a timestamp. I could not figure out how to convert it to some integer sequence or something like that

Comment: @Luca that is why I am using .iloc which is by position not by index value